# Heroku Syncdb Import Error

Tags: python, heroku, import, production, migrate

Hey whenever I try to syncdb with heroku, I'm getting errors because migrations from before that used an app that i uninstaleld (image crop) cannot find the module or something...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'image_cropping'
```

I have tried to include image cropping now but i get the same error. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings variable value. Also: did your try removing all `.pyc` files?